# Need help analyzing a circuit?

Tags: led, amplifier, resistors, diodes

so basically i ran on this schematic , an led Color Organ from Circuit Skills. Now following the explanation of the circuit i pretty much understand the basic principle of it. However i have some problems figuring out about two things(I am an entry level Electronics hobbyist, so sorry about the dumb questions). [image] 
Q1: The elements following the op amp (Red Rectangle) are supposed to condition the signal (ac signal from the aux jack), however are they really necessary ? And what is their purpose ? The ones in the yellow box i think are for smoothing the blinking of the Leds in order not the blink instantly but add a little dimming effect.

Q2: Here in the circuit they use "Virtual Ground" for the Op Amps, however can they be powered by a single supply ?

Hope i can get some answers from the Electronic Gurus .
P.S. Here is the link from the website [Circuit Skills](https://makezine.com/2010/10/18/circuit-skills-led-color-organ-spon/)

Comment: Each part serves a purpose to provide fast attack and hold with slower decay, so you can see what you heard. Critical choices were made by some designer for C ratios and RC=T decay times. and Imax=CdV/dt charge times.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt why do your comments read like word salad?  Know your audience and says things in terms others can understand.  Nobel laureate Richard Feynman explained about trees growing out of air rather than the ground:  A tree eats air, chomps down on airborne carbon dioxide, then uses sunshine to pull the carbon dioxide apart, gets rid of the oxygen, which it spits back into the air, leaving the carbon and water, the stuff to make the substance of the tree.  Be like Richard.

Comment: If these terms are unfamiliar to you, then you are unlike all the techs I have worked with. You should know C ratios are like R ratios for sound diode peak detected envelope attenuation .While the shunt RC=T determines decay time

Comment: But if you cut off the roots , the tree will die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1: The elements following the op amp (Red Rectangle) are supposed to
>   condition the signal (ac signal from the aux jack), however are they
>   really necessary ? And what is their purpose ? The ones in the yellow
>   box i think are for smoothing the blinking of the Leds in order not
>   the blink instantly but add a little dimming effect

It functions like a half wave rectifier (only using the positive portion of the wave coming into it and the cap and resistor filter it. You may be able to drive the transistor directly but it might not give you the effect you want. The other problem with driving the transistor directly is you would at minimum need a resistor to separate the low impedance sink of the transistor from the feedback network of the op amp. (there transistor might sink too much current and eliminating the cap could affect your sound signals)

> Q2: Here in the circuit they use "Virtual Ground" for the Op Amps,
>   however can they be powered by a single supply ?

Virtual grounds are typically used for cables and other situations when your ground cant be trusted (like battery powered applications) to force the ground to be 0V. In this case, its not really a virtual ground, it's a reference functioning at half of the supply voltage and probably exists to create a bias current (which is really weird). The best thing would be to try it with the virutal ground or without and see which is better for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit in the red rectangle is an **AM detector** or **peak detector**. The diode is an essential part of the circuit. The diode will conduct if the input voltage is higher than the voltage across the capacitor to ground on its right.

Dave from the EEVBlog made a video about peak detectors, [go watch it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jllsqRWhjGM)

Here the peak detector basically translates the amplitude of the audio signal (and more amplitude means louder) into a changing DC voltage to control the lights.

The virtual ground circuit in the blue rectangle is a way to prevent having to use a symmetrical supply voltage. A symmetrical supply voltage could be for example +10 V, ground and -10 V. That requires a slightly more complex power supply than a "normal" (non-symmetric) powersupply.

Opamps are easier to work with if you use a symmetric supply but if you want to avoid that you can "fake" it using this virtual ground circuit. If you have a +20V and ground supply (so non-symmetrical) this circuit would generate +10 V as an extra voltage. When we then use this +10 V as a **reference voltage** for the opamps (note how the opamp's + inputs are all connected to it instead of to the real ground) then this +10 V becomes a "virtual ground". It's not the circuit's real ground but for the opamps it is the ground. When this virtual grounding scheme is done properly, the opamps aren't able to tell the difference and will behave the same. But note that the opamp's outputs might have a DC voltage on them, in this case it would be +10 V. That's why in this circuit there are capacitors at the opamp's outputs, they block that DC voltage.

Comment: So basically it has to have a virtual ground , instead of connecting it to the ground of a DC supply ?

Answer (score 0):

The virtual ground opamp is not needed in this circuit because its voltage divider and filter capacitor can be calculated or simply made 4 times the existing current to make the half supply voltage reference voltage for the very low input current on the (+) inputs of the other opamps.